# Calculating margin-top value to occupy remaining height in fluid design

Tags: html, css, margin, fluid-layout

Basically, the container has both fluid height and width. Kindly consider the following:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="header">Hello!</span>
   <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Both of the `box` divs take say 40% height each, assume I apply 15% height for the `span` element and the remaining 5% for its `margin-top` value. As expected it will not sum up to 100% of the `container` height since 
`margin-top` is calculated based on the width as far as I know. How do I calculate the `margin-top` percentage value in this case so all elements including the margin would sum up to the full height of the `container`? here's my CSS Code, thanks in advance.

```
.container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

.header {
    height: 15%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5%;         /*how to calculate this correctly*/   
}

.box {
    height: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can easily obtain what you want by using flexbox and `margin-top:auto` on `header`:

```css
body,html {
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
}

.container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  border:1px solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.header {
  flex:0 0 15%;
  background:red;
  align-self: flex-start; /* To have same visual behavior as inline-block */
  margin-top:auto /* this will do the trick*/
}

.box {
  flex:0 0 40%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="header">Hello!</span>
  <div class="box">a</div>
  <div class="box">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted  to know how to implement it without using flexbox as i am not looking for an alternative.

Comment: @MrShabana well there is no way to make margin consider height .. so you need to find workarounds like the other solution for example or consider modern ways like flexbox where the value auto is exactly what you want :) as am sure your issue is a common issue and techniques like flexbox was created for such things ;)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer flexbox solution by @Temani, but in case you need to support old version of browsers like IE that does not support flexbox.

You can just add an empty span before header or use pseudo css element and give it a 5% height, this will give you the same margin top effect you need even for old browsers.

```css
html,
body{
  height:100%;
}

.container {
   display:inline-block;
   height: 80%;
   width: 80%;
   background-color:red;
}

.container:before {
  content:" ";
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  height:5%;
  background-color:red
}

.header {
   height: 15%;
   width:100%;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color:blue
}

.box {
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
   height: 40%;
   background-color:green
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="header">Hello!</span>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be better to consider pseudo element instead, so no markup change :)

Comment: It's not a browser support issue and i am not looking for an alternative. I was hoping to know how to calculate the value if possible.

Comment: @MrShaban yeah i understand it's just the fact that margin-top percentage is calculated based on width, the browser support is for flexbox solution, regarding how to calculate it i don't think this is possible

Comment: you also need to add `height:100%` to body and html so that your code is correct, actually it's not .. as there is no height set to parent

Comment: euh, another issue too : don't make the pseudo element inline-block or you will face whitespace issue because the header is also inline-block. Make it block element instead and then it should be good :)